# Moving a vector of objects to another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to move an object from vector to another and the delete that vector.

```
std::vector <SDI::navalVessels*> SDI::fleet::remove(std::string param, std::string data)
{
  vector<navalVessels*> searchFleet;

  if (param == "name")
  {
    for (int i = 0; i<fleetList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(fleetList[i] -> getName() == data)
        {
            searchFleet[0] = std::move(fleetList[i]);
            searchFleet.clear();
        }
    }
 }
```

getName() is a getter.
Fleetlist is a vector of objects.
SeachFleet is temporary vector.

im sure what I am trying to do would ony require a few lines of built in vector functions but i am not sure as how i can go about it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you rename the variables? The code isn't terribly clear or it looks incomplete

Comment: @Marco yes i did as I thought my original code was slightly confusing perhaps. maybe i was overthinking it. I'll uploaded the original

Comment: I miserably fail to see the point in the above code.. are you trying to move one item from fleetList (whose declaration I ignore) to searchFleet or what?

Comment: It seems to do what the question says, `move` objects from one `vector` to another and then "delete" that (target) `vector`. Not sure that's what it should do.

Comment: What is the point of what you are attempting to do? Or, what problem are you trying to solve (in case this is an XY problem.)

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to search for all vessels by name and then you're trying to delete them from some list called fleetlist. What exactly is fleetlist? Your code does not specify its type. Does that kind of summarize what you're trying to do? It would help if you stated in plain english what exactly it is, because it is quite apparent you're going about it in the wrong way.

Comment: I'd like to add that despite the name, std::move isn't used to "move objects from one vector to another".. a simple assignment might be sufficient if you have a vector of pointers. And also: destroying the element from the old vector should be accomplished with vector::erase or the like

Comment: at the moment, it finds an object in vector (fleetlist), gets that object. Then what I want to do, is move that object into a temporary vector and delete that vector completely thus removing that object within that vector. does this make more sense?

Comment: Not entirely to me.. 1) Move the object into a temporary vector 2) Remove the temporary vector? Thus destroying the object? If you want to delete an element from the fleetList (assuming it's a vector of some kind) you can use erase (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

Comment: I don't really understand this code either, but as the searchFleet vector holds Pointers, I assume the original vector does too, so as far as I can tell you only move the pointer and then throw that away, causing a memory leak?

Comment: If you are trying to just remove items from a container you might want to look into the standard algorithms such as `std::remove_if` if you want to copy items from a container to another container you might use `std::copy_if` in either case if you are removing these pointers from a vector and not calling delete on them anywhere you may have a memory leak if they point to data on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

"*I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.*" With apologies to Mr Babbage.

You have a `vector` of pointers so `std::move` has no observable effect here and is not appropriate for your problem in any case.

If I understand you correctly, you just want to remove some elements from a `vector`. This is what `vector::erase` is for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fleetList.size(); ) // no increment here
{
    if (fleetList[i]->getName() == data)
        fleetList.erase(i);
    else
        i++; // only increment if the element is not erased
}
```

But it's too easy to make a mistake with this kind of code; this is what `std::remove_if` is for:

```
fleetList.erase(std::remove_if(fleetList.begin(), fleetList.end(),
                               [&](navalVessels* fleet){
                                   return fleet->getName() == data;
                               }),
                fleetList.end());
```

In neither case will the object pointed to by the pointer(s) be deleted. If you want that then you should either use smart pointers (recommended) or manually `delete` them yourself:

```
auto newEnd = std::partition(fleetList.begin(), fleetList.end(),
                             [&](navalVessels* fleet){
                                 return fleet->getName() != data; // inverted condition
                             });
std::for_each(newEnd, fleetList.end(), [](navalVessels* fleet){ delete fleet; });
fleetList.erase(newEnd, fleetList.end());
```

Or with the raw loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fleetList.size(); ) // no increment here
{
    if (fleetList[i]->getName() == data) {
        delete fleetList[i];
        fleetList.erase(i);
    } else {
        i++; // only increment if the element is not erased
    }
}
```

Comment: It was all good until the `delete` part in the `for_each`. `remove_if` can leave pointers that you *don't* want to call `delete` on at the end of the vector. What it does is keep the good stuff at the beginning. But the end section is not necessarily bad stuff. The raw loop doesn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza You mean because `remove_if` leaves elements in the range `[newEnd,end)` in a "valid but unspecified" state? Yes, that is awkward, I hadn't thought of that. I will rewrite it to use `std::partition` instead. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that was it exactly. Nice use of `std::partition`. +1.